# Scandir does not work in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, scandir

I'm trying to put a slideshow in Joomla, for this slideshow i want it to get all images for a folder, i use this code:

```
$dir = '/images/slideshow/breda';
$files = scandir($dir);
print_r($files);
echo '<div class="flexslider">';
    echo '<ul class="slides">';
        foreach($files as $file) {
            echo '<li><img src="/images/slideshow/breda/';
            echo $file;
            echo '" alt="" title="" /></li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
print_r($file);
```

When i use print_r it does not give any data back.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: your path is absolute, did you want to say `dirname(__FILE__) . $dir`; ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider using Joomla coding standards for this like so:

```
$path = JPATH_SITE . '/images/slideshow/breda/';
$files = JFolder::files($path);
print_r($files);
echo '<div class="flexslider">';
    echo '<ul class="slides">';
        foreach($files as $file) {
            echo '<li><img src="/images/slideshow/breda/';
            echo $file;
            echo '" alt="" title="" /></li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
print_r($file);
```

I haven't tested what I've quickly mocked up, so please let me know if it works or not and I can update accordingly :)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I used glob in my component which worked for me:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

An example of use:

```
$directory = 'images'.DS.'images'.DS;
$images = glob($directory . "{*.jpg,*.png,*.gif}",GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($images as $image){

Echo $image;

}
```

Always best to use Joomla coding standards if possible.

Hope it helps.